# How to add more than four keyboard layouts in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout

How to add more than four keyboard layouts in Ubuntu 12.04?

I am surprised that I can't add more than four language keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it seems impossible to set up more than 4 keyboard layouts in Ubuntu.

A workaround would be to enable keyboard shortcuts that would execute a special command to switch to a particular keyboard layout.

Therefore:

- Go to **System Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**
- Add the first new custom shortcut, let's say "US English", with command `setxkbmap us`. Then, once you press Ok on it, set the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
- Then, add "Greek' for example, with command `setxkbmap gr` and shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
- You can add more layouts.

**Look into `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` for the correct layout file (like 'us', 'gr').**

You then switch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.

Comment: i put this for german `setxkbmap ger` and i presse CTRL+F1 after assigning them to the customed shourtcut ,but it doesnt work it still doesnt change

Comment: No way, I said, look into `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` for the correct layout file. You should use `setxkbmap de` or `setxkbmap ge` for german language, I think.